# Python - VortexaSDK - UnfulfilledArgumentError: No value for found "bounding_box"

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using Vortexa's SDK (with python 3.9.9) and running the below in a Jupyter Notebook - any help with understanding this error would be appreciated!:

`tarragona = [g.id for g in Geographies().search("tarragona").to_list() if "port" in g.layer]`

JN pushes out this error:

```
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_6980/4117263886.py in <module>
----> 1 tarragona = [g.id for g in Geographies().search("tarragona").to_list() if "port" in g.layer]

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\vortexasdk\endpoints\geographies_result.py in to_list(self)
     17         """Represent geographies as a list."""
     18         # noinspection PyTypeChecker
---> 19         return create_list(super().to_list(), Geography)
     20 
     21     def to_df(self, columns=None) -> pd.DataFrame:

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\vortexasdk\result_conversions.py in create_list(list_of_dicts, output_class)
     12     """Convert each list element into an instance of the output class."""
     13     logger.debug(f"Converting list of dictionaries to list of {output_class}")
---> 14     return [output_class.from_dict(d) for d in list_of_dicts]
     15 
     16 

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\vortexasdk\result_conversions.py in <listcomp>(.0)
     12     """Convert each list element into an instance of the output class."""
     13     logger.debug(f"Converting list of dictionaries to list of {output_class}")
---> 14     return [output_class.from_dict(d) for d in list_of_dicts]
     15 
     16 

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\vortexasdk\api\serdes.py in from_dict(cls, d)
     17     def from_dict(cls: T, d: Dict) -> T:
     18         """Serialize dictionary to dataclass of type T."""
---> 19         return jsons.loads(jsons.dumps(d), cls)

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\jsons\_load_impl.py in loads(str_, cls, jdkwargs, *args, **kwargs)
    145                           'valid JSON.', str_, cls, err)
    146     else:
--> 147         return load(obj, cls, *args, **kwargs)
    148 
    149 

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\jsons\_load_impl.py in load(json_obj, cls, strict, fork_inst, attr_getters, **kwargs)
     95     }
     96 
---> 97     return _do_load(json_obj, deserializer, cls, initial, **kwargs_)
     98 
     99 

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\jsons\_load_impl.py in _do_load(json_obj, deserializer, cls, initial, **kwargs)
    104              **kwargs):
    105     try:
--> 106         result = deserializer(json_obj, cls, **kwargs)
    107         validate(result, cls, kwargs['fork_inst'])
    108     except Exception as err:

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\jsons\deserializers\default_object.py in default_object_deserializer(obj, cls, key_transformer, strict, **kwargs)
     37     obj, kwargs = _check_and_transform_keys(obj, key_transformer, **kwargs)
     38     kwargs['strict'] = strict
---> 39     constructor_args = _get_constructor_args(obj, cls, **kwargs)
     40     remaining_attrs = _get_remaining_args(obj, cls, constructor_args,
     41                                           strict, kwargs['fork_inst'])

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\jsons\deserializers\default_object.py in _get_constructor_args(obj, cls, meta_hints, attr_getters, **kwargs)
     61     for sig_key, sig in signature_parameters.items():
     62         if sig_key != 'self':
---> 63             key, value = _get_value_for_attr(obj=obj,
     64                                              orig_cls=cls,
     65                                              meta_hints=meta_hints,

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\jsons\deserializers\default_object.py in _get_value_for_attr(obj, cls, orig_cls, sig_key, sig, meta_hints, attr_getters, **kwargs)
    108         result = sig_key, None
    109     else:
--> 110         raise UnfulfilledArgumentError(
    111             'No value found for "{}"'.format(sig_key), sig_key, obj, orig_cls)
    112     return result

UnfulfilledArgumentError: No value found for "bounding_box"
```